# How to determine what character would be at a given index in a sorted string without hashing or sorting?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, hash

We are given with a **string** and an **integer**. We have to tell what **character** would be at that **integer position** in the string if the characters were to be placed into sort order.

**For Example**

```
String = LALIT  
Index = 3  
Sorted string  AILLT and the character at position 3 is L
```

Is it possible to solve this problem without sorting?
if yes then can someone provide a **pseudo code**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do this. You're looking for something called a [*selection algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) which, given a list of elements and a number *k*, returns what element would be in position *k* if the elements were to be in sorted order. Amazingly enough, it's possible to do this without sorting the entire list!

The simplest non-sorting algorithm for selection is called [*quickselect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), which runs in expected time O(n) and, provided you're allowed to modify the original array, uses only O(1) auxiliary storage space. The idea behind quickselect is to do a single step of quicksort - pick a pivot element, partition the elements into elements less than the pivot, elements equal to the pivot, and elements greater than the pivot - then to see what happens based on that. If the pivot element ends up in position *k* after this step, then you're done - that's the element that would be at position *k* in the final sequence. If the pivot is at a position higher than *k*, recursively look to the left of the pivot (the *k*th smallest element is somewhere in there), and if the pivot is at a position lower than *k*, recursively look to the right of the pivot (the *k*th smallest element is somewhere in there).

Other approaches exist as well, such as the median-of-medians algorithm that always runs in worst-case O(n) time but is a classic "tricky algorithm to wrap your head around."

Comment: Another straightforward linear algorithm is to count character frequencies, then cumulatively scan the histogram to infer the character position corresponding to the index. In practice this is workable for 8-bit character sets but unlikely to be a win for full unicode.

Comment: @doynax Absolutely. I had bundled that under "hashing" (with an identity hash) or "sorting" (it's basically counting sort) in a loose sense and so didn't account for here.

Comment: Can you elaborate? You may want to post that as a separate question on the site.